# Инициализация двух массивов

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
using namespace std;

class massive {
private:
    int b[4];
public:
massive() {
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        b[i] = 1 + rand() % 10;
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
};

int main() {
   massive a;
   massive b;
   return 0;
}
```

Почему при выполнении кода оба массива постоянно инициализируются (или, по крайней мере, выводятся на экран) одинаковыми числами? https://www.onlinegdb.com/edit/B1wiCeG2m

Comment: srand нужно вызывать один раз, а не перед каждой чередой вызовов rand.

Comment: `time(0)` возвращает время в секундах, поэтому практически во всех запусках значение, передаваемое в `srand()`, будет одним и тем же.

Answer (score 3):

Так происходит потому что srand(time(0)); нужно вызывать в функции main, тогда у тебя будут разные значения.

Вот рабочий код.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class massive
{
  private:
    int b[4];

  public:
    massive()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            b[i] = 1 + rand() % 10;
            cout << b[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    massive a;
    massive b;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]